# How to design new flip flop using JK flip flop

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, counter

I have an excitation table that called MN flip flop like below.

```
Q Q' M N
0 0  0 X
0 1  1 X
1 0  X 0
1 1  X 1
```

I try to design a counter that count 0-7-2-3 in Proteus. In my estimation, this excitation table is like JK flip flop's excitation table and if I use not gate for K values, I find N values, is that possible like that converting? If not, how can I design flip flops like above that has excitation table for Proteus design. Any offers?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Build a state machine diagram.  Figure out the patterns by which one state goes to the next.  The inputs are the current state and any inputs, and the output is the next state.  Then add the JK excitation that brings you to the next state.  Make sure, at this point, that you have no duplicate states *(i.e. states that with the same input that end up at all the same outputs)* and eliminate them if you do. Once you have this, then start building Karnough maps for the outputs and JK excitations until you feel like you are ready to implement the resulting logic.